# How to import an existing android Project into another android project

Tags: android, import, project, addition

i want to import an existing Android Project(a small App that should be added to another Android Project soon) into another Android Project in order to test.

I tried several things for example:

- export the first project als jar and add the external jar to build path of the second
- added the first project to the second in the build path of the second project

but nothing worked
and i did not forget to mark the checkbox at "order and Export"
i'll be very happy, if anyone could help me ;)

hannes

Comment: Inside another project or in your workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project Build Path>Configure Build Path> "Select prject tab"
then add the project :D

Hope it helps 
Have fun

Comment: thanks for your answer but that did not work... I tried first project: properties->android->libraries activate checkbox "is library"  Second project: properties->android->libraries->add add the first project as library :)

Answer (score 3):

there are a couple of different solutions imo.

If applicable - you could mark the first small project as a library and just add it to the newer project (properties -> android -> checkbox/add lib)

OR

You access the app if its already installed on the device

OR

You copy the source code/package to the new project

OR

You compile the old project to a dex file and load the classes/methods via the DexClassLoader

OR

export as JAR file, as you already tried - but you cant export any resources (although there are workarounds if there arent many resources)

Thats all I can think of right now, if you have more specific question to one of the solutions, just ask  =)