# How to add an android studio project to another android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-module

I want to add an android studio project to my existing android studio project but when i try to import another module from file->import module then i get an error saying the app module already exists.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346448/how-to-import-an-existing-android-project-into-another-android-project

Comment: No, this doesnt really solve my issue.

Comment: Okay , the error that you are facing I think is this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172065/project-already-contains-module-with-this-name-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your module name while i porting old project to new one 
as shown in image

[image]